# Cast DataRowView as a typed row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**-update start**

Unable to cast object of type 'namespace.Student' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

```
 <%# FixNull(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row, "Name")%>

 protected string FixNull(DataRow dr, string fieldName)
        {
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (!dr.IsNull(fieldName))
                    return (dr[fieldName]).ToString();            }
            return "&nbsp;";
        }
```

**-update end**

in the below method expecting an object, so how would i cast it to that type? i always get null no matter what column.

calling from .aspx:

```
<%# FixNull((mynamespace.Student)(Container.DataItem), "CreatedBy")%>
```

.CS

```
 protected string FixNull(object dataItem, string fieldName)
        {
            if (dataItem != null)
            {
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataItem;
                if (drv != null) //always getting null
                {
                    if (!drv.Row.IsNull(fieldName))
                        return (drv[fieldName]).ToString();                     
                }
            }            
            return "&nbsp;";
        }
```

Comment: Silly question: have you put a breakpoint on the line `if (dataItem != null)` and used the debugger to inspect `dataItem` and determine what type it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how should be done:

```
<%# Eval("Name") == null ? "&nbsp;" : Eval("Name")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the help from this article:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38669/Using-Formatting-Functions-with-GridView-Template-.aspx

**Updated...**

Try the given code:

**ASPX:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvSample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# FixNull(Container.DataItem ,"ID") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# FixNull(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row, "Code") %>  <!--updated here-->
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvSample.DataSource = GetData();
        gvSample.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 1;
        dr["Code"] = null;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = 2;
        dr["Code"] = "Karan";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        return dt;
    }



protected string FixNull(object dataItem,string fieldname)
{
    if (dataItem != null)
    {
       //updated here
        //DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataItem;
        //if (drv != null)
        //{
        //    if (!drv.Row.IsNull(fieldname))          
        //        return (drv[fieldname]).ToString();
        //}
        DataRowView drv;
        DataRow dr;
        if (dataItem is DataRowView)
        {
            drv = (DataRowView)dataItem;
            if (drv != null)
            {
                if (!drv.Row.IsNull(fieldname))
                    return (drv[fieldname]).ToString();
            }
        }
        if (dataItem is DataRow)
        {
            dr = (DataRow)dataItem;
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (!dr.IsNull(fieldname))
                    return dr[fieldname].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return "&nbsp;";
}
```

Comment: @Suki, why would i create datatable on fly? and more over my object get populated through objectdatasource.

Comment: Did u try this code in your sample project to see how its working fine even if there is a null value in "Code" column. Only get the concept from this code.I don't want to you to change your code as there are many ways to bind a gridView.

Comment: i dont see how the code is different then mine? i am taking about `FixNull` i am passing the `object, columnName` from .aspx like this: 
`<%# FixNull(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row, "Name")%> `

Comment: see the update answer i think that might be that u want with " <%# FixNull(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row, "Name")%> ". Well,the answer posted by you would be the best one to handle null value.More than that u don't need to check null value for a particular column because GridView automatic handle but strictly if you want "&nbsp;" in place of null then your solution is OK.